# Object name from variable in Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object, syntax, actionscript

I am trying to use the string in a variable to create an item in an object.

Example non functioning code:

```
    private var myName:String = 'group1';

    private var _ins:Object = {
        myName : { 
            data1: arr[0],
            data2: arr[1]               
        }
    }
```

I can not understand what syntax to use to make myName be 'group1' text. Currently I am using:

```
    private var _ins:Object = {
        'group1' : { 
            data1: arr[0],
            data2: arr[1]               
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax of generic objects in AS3 allow to omit quotes for the keys, but actually your code is:

```
private var myName:String = 'group1';

private var _ins:Object = {
    "myName" : { 
        "data1": arr[0],
        "data2": arr[1]               
    }
}
```

You should use myName as a variable, which contains a key.

```
private var myName:String = 'group1';

private var _ins:Object = {};

_ins[myName] = { 
    data1: arr[0],
    data2: arr[1]               
};
```

Comment: Great, I now understand.